# Error trying to open assets/database.db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to attach a database - prepopulated with information to my application.  I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) however when I try to run through my database helper I am getting an error.

Here is my helper code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class WorkoutsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String DATABASE_PATH = "/src/main/assets/";

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workoutsDatabase.db";

    // Workouts table name
    private static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS = "workouts";

    // Workouts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_LAST_NAME = "hero_last_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_FIRST_NAME = "hero_first_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_MIDDLE_NAME = "hero_middle_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_DESCRIPTION = "hero_description";
    private static final String KEY_DATE_ADDED = "date_added";
    private static final String KEY_WORKOUT = "workout";
    private static final String KEY_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";
    private static final String KEY_PHOTO = "photo";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    // Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if(dbExist) {
            // Do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

        Log.d("Workouts DB", "Database Created");

    }

    //Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
    //@return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            // Database doesn't exist yet
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws android.database.SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDatabase != null)
            myDatabase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

 }
```

Here is the log:

```
04-25 11:03:15.538  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-25 11:03:15.610  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <gl_external_unsized_fmt_to_sized:2379>: QCOM> format, datatype mismatch
04-25 11:03:15.610  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <get_texture_formats:3009>: QCOM> Invalid format!
04-25 11:03:16.691  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
04-25 11:03:16.691  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/src/main/assets/workoutsDatabase.db) -
04-25 11:03:16.702  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/src/main/assets/workoutsDatabase.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.checkDatabase(WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java:81)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.createDatabase(WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java:54)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 11:03:16.742  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-25 11:03:16.742  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d4d40)
04-25 11:03:16.745  11852-11852/com.rcd.mypr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rcd.mypr, PID: 11852
    java.lang.Error: Error copying database
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.createDatabase(WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java:66)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My database is called workoutsDatabase.db and it lives in src/main/assets

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: You are using incorrectly the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. When you extends from it, you must work with the `onCreate` method in order to initialize your database `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: @CommmonsWare - I have never added an external library like that before.  Would I just download the library folder and include that in my "libs" folder, and then make the necessary changes in my helper file?

Comment: `DATABASE_PATH = "/src/main/assets/";` seems completely mistaken, at the very least something that would not be available are runtime.  Where did you get that path from?

Comment: Thats where I manually put the .db file... app/src/main/assets/databases (ive since changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are following this tutorial, but you changed the path name of the output DB.  You can't just pick any directory you want to for placing the DB.  In fact the call to getReadableDatabase will always create the db in: /data/data/YOUR PACKAGE NAME FROM THE ANDROID MANIFEST/databases so you need to change DATABASEPATH to be that.

[Package your own sqlite DB](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: Thank you, i reverted my changes and modified a few things, and it works now! :)